# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' in discord bot

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord

I have been working on a discord bot for practice and one of the commands is supposed to pull the best percentile a character has from FFLOGS.  I can get the the link to the API call with the relevant data but as of now it's simply pulling AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'. Any suggestions will help!

IDE: PyCharm

Here is the output in console:

```
https://www.fflogs.com/v1/parses/character/Draco%20O'larn/Leviathan/NA?api_key=8e4792ff39bcc1157b86ea73f7741fb4
Ignoring exception in command bestPct:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FFLogBotv2\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/FFLogBotv2/fflogsbotv2.py", line 31, in bestPct
    message = fflogs_request.best_percentile_of("{} {}".format(firstName, lastName), server, region)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FFLogBotv2\utils\fflogs.py", line 143, in best_percentile_of
    job = best_of_specs[i].get('spec')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FFLogBotv2\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FFLogBotv2\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\FFLogBotv2\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here is the code in question:

```
    def best_percentile_of(self, name, server, region):
        url = self.get_parses_url(character="character", name=name, server=server, region=region)
        response = self.make_request(url)

        columns = ['job', 'name', 'best_dps', 'best_hist_pct']
        best_of_data = []
        if response.ok:
            json_response = response.json()
            for encounter in json_response:
                best_of_specs = encounter['spec']
                for i, value in enumerate(best_of_specs):
                    job = best_of_specs[i].get('spec')
                    best_hist_pct = best_of_specs[i].get('best_historical_percent')
                    best_dps = best_of_specs[i].get('best_persecondamount')
                    best_of_data.append((job, name, best_dps, best_hist_pct))
        return pd.DataFrame(data=best_of_data, columns=columns)
```

This is the function of the command:

```
@bot.command()
async def bestPct(ctx, firstName=None, lastName=None, server=None, region=None):
    if all([firstName, lastName, server, region]):
        message = fflogs_request.best_percentile_of("{} {}".format(firstName, lastName), server, region)
    else:
        message = """Usage: !bestPct <firstName> <lastName> <server> <region>"""
    await ctx.channel.send(message)
```

Comment: You're using `enumerate()`, so why are you using `best_of_specs[i]` instead of `value`?

Comment: The error indicates that `best_of_specs` is not a list of dictionaries, it's a list of strings.

Comment: And why are you using `enumerate()`? Just use `for value in best_of_specs:`

Comment: What does `print(best_of_specs)` show?

Comment: `print(best_of_specs` prints what jobs were used to clear the encounter

Comment: I meant for you to show the actual output so we can see the the type and nesting. Because it's apparently not what you think it is. Put it in the question, not a comment.